# How would you call a market for kidney donors and recipients?

Tags: microeconomics

I was wondering how you would call a market for kidney donors and recipients, where you have many 'buyers' and many 'sellers'. However, the 'seller' can only 'sell' his/her 'product' once. Since it's illegal to sell kidneys, the market structure is a little bit vague for me to categorize. Suppose selling and buying kidneys would be legal, how would that market be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, these types of markets are called [matching markets](http://ieor.berkeley.edu/~ieor151/lecture_notes/ieor151_lec7.pdf). That's also the same term given to a variety of economic decisions and market structures, from [school choice](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~lyariv/ConferencePapers/Abdulkadiroglu.pdf) to some types of [marriage problems](http://www.econ.ku.dk/cam/Files/Autumn2003/workshop/Yoram%20Weiss%20share14.pdf).